# Yahoo OpenID + OAuth, how to get users login email

Tags: email, authentication, oauth, openid

Can anyone provide example on how to get users login email for yahoo by using [OpenID + OAuth](https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/openid_connect/getting_started.html)?
I use [socialauth](https://github.com/3pillarlabs/socialauth) so java would would be preferred language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a big problem in Yahoo Oauth system and i suspect you will also going to face same problem as one of my team mate is going through.

He is facing the following problem
in his yahoo email id he has set primary id as his `gmail` id and when yahoo send back profile information it send back that `gmail` id as primary email with no information which is the account email id

So i am not sure how we can fetch the account email id of the logged in user (i.e yahoo email).

Just to give you an idea you have to get first guid from yahoo and than send a request to the following end point

```
http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/{guid}/profile?format=json
```

if you able to access user account email-id please share your findings.
FYI: we are using scribe-java API for OAuth

here is the question posted by my team mate
[Getting user Email Yahoo Oauth (using Scribe-Java API)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311972/getting-user-email-yahoo-oauth-using-scribe-java-api)

Comment: @MatBanik:agree and i am sure they will confirm it with user but it seems the shole idea going other way around you made user to login using Yahoo but his/her email id is say of `gmail`.One option seems possible is attribute exchange being offered by yahoo.If we find any inputs will share with you

Comment: i am wondering are you able to get the yahoo email id or the user or not?

Comment: OK!! well just an update for you Oauth along will give you back emails but not sure if it will return yahoo email,so we are switching to OpenID and oauth combination.Will update my post.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I had a similar issue getting user's email, turns out when creating app on yahoo developer console you need to select the option for Profile: Read/Write Public and Private 
once this is done  you can now get users email as an array with a key "primary" having true or false to know which is the primary mail

Answer (score 0):

Use the [userinfo](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#UserInfoResponse) endpoint:

```
$ curl -s -H 'Authorization: Bearer <access_token>' https://api.login.yahoo.com/openid/v1/userinfo | jq .email
alice@example.com
```

The endpoint url can be [discovered](https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/openid_connect/discovery.html) with:

```
$ curl -s https://api.login.yahoo.com/.well-known/openid-configuration | jq -r .userinfo_endpoint
https://api.login.yahoo.com/openid/v1/userinfo
```