# Getting user Email Yahoo Oauth (using Scribe-Java API)

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, scribe, yahoo-oauth

Trying to access user profile from Yahoo using Oauth system and for that i am taking help of Scribe-Java API
its working fine except one issue whcih i am sure not related to the API i am using

In my yahoo profile i have following settings

```
Yahoo! Email  --->amy_yahoo_id@yahoo.com  

Email--->other_id@gmail.com Primary - Change
```

So what i am getting back is `other_id@gmail.com` which means i am not able to get correct information of the logged in user.Once i am able to get guid i am sending the request to following URL

```
http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/guid/profile?format=json
```

any way i can get the yahoo mail id to which user is associated in place of other id even if that is set as primary or along with any other email id all i want is to get the yahoo mail id of the user by which he/she logged in to the system.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any specific reason you must get the yahoo account's email?

I also facing the same problem as you earlier.
After think over, primary email means to be the contactable email for the user.
So may be that's why yahoo make it that way.
Of course it will be good if they can provide one more email which is account's email.
But if you just want to have unique identifier, we can use the guid.
So may be you can check again, does your requirement must have the account's email?
or you just need an email where user set primary because they preferred to be contactable by that email?

Now I will just make use of the primary email return from Yahoo for my OAuth